# Handle select multiple on django

Tags: python, django

I have this on template

```
<select name="document" id="document" multiple="">
        <option value="2">test 1</option>
        <option value="3">test 2</option>
</select>
```

When I select two options when I accept the request in views.py I got correctly 2 options selected

```
self.request.POST // It prints 'document': ['2', '3']
```

But when I try to select the field like this

```
self.request.POST['document'] // It prints only '3'
```

How can I select 2 options?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`.getlist(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to obtain all the values associated with a given key.

You thus can here work with:

```
request.POST.getlist('document')
```

Comment: I'm doing the same as your solutions :

 <select class="custom-select" required="" name="permitions" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
            {% for permitions in permitions %}
            <option value="{{permitions.name}}">{{permitions.name}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

post_permission = request.POST.getlist("permitions")


but it's doesn't work. it only saves the last select value